# React-router-dom goBack(), how to inherit prop from another js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My route path is in separated file that contains only routes, nothing more and this is the only file that I'm importing in it `React-router-dom`. 
The thing is, I want to specify a button in another js file, that will do goBack() function but I don't want to import `react-router-dom` here, but inherit prop from the main js file.
So, I have added to my App.js this lines (this is the main file that only have routes)

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.goBack=this.goBack.bind(this);
    }

    goBack(){
        this.props.history.goBack();
    }
```

And the button

```
<button onClick={this.goBack}>Go Back</button>
```

Is there a way to do it that way or I really need to import `router-dom` and add constructor to another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to import `router-dom` on your new file. You just need to pass down the `history` prop all the way to the button component. Alternatively, set the history prop in a context or redux store variable - hopefully your back button is not nested deep in your component tree. Tip: Try to have your component using router props shallow in your tree to avoid passing through router props.

My router is set up something like:

```
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Public exact path="/" component={ConnectedLoginForm} {...props} />
                <Route  path="/recover-password" component={ConnectedRecoverPasswordForm}  />
                <Route  path="/reset-password/:token" component={ConnectedResetPasswordForm} />
                <Route  path="/invite/:token" component={ConnectedAcceptInviteForm} />
                <Public  path="/login" component={ConnectedLoginForm} {...props} />
                <Authenticated path="/:co_id" component={ConnectedMainView} {...props} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Thus I have access to `history` prop in my `ConnectedMainView` component.

Comment: That is what I'm asking for. And yes, it's not nested that deep. But I don't know how to get access to that prop. My Main file almost the same.
When I add `<button onClick={this.props.goBack()}>Go Back</button>` to another js file it's getting me error.

Comment: So you did pass down the props from the router? `{...props}` or `history={props.history}` to your Route component all the way down to your button component? what do you get if you log `this.props.history` in your  button component?

Comment: You need to pass down the `history.goBack` reference all the way to the button component, else you will not have access to it in the button component.

Comment: Wait a minute, do I need to install `history package`? BrowserHistory is not a part of react-router-dom anymore?

Comment: I'm on `"react-router-dom": "4.2.2"` and do not have history installed.

Comment: Hmm, if I pass `{...props}` its getting me error that props is not defined.

Comment: Try spreading {...this.props}, when you are in a full component. `const MyComp = (props) => (<OtherComp {...props} />); ` for simple component. When you use full class definition with context in `this`, use `render () { return <OtherComp {...this.props} />;}`

Comment: Okay, `this.props` go smooth, but from another file, I still cannot get access to that prop. I tried `onClick={this.history.goBack()}`, `onClick={this.props.goBack()}`, `onClick={history.goBack()}` but didn't work. Error goBack() is not a function. Btw, I have changed from <button> to <a>. Hope this will not complicate things.

Comment: Okay, I was able to make it work. `onClick={this.props.history.goBack}` works. Thank you for help :)

Comment: first log `this.props.history` in the button component render and make sure that you have `this.props.history.goBack()` available, then also do `onClick={() => this.props.history.goBack()}` if `onClick={this.props.history.goBack}` does not work. Writing `onClick={this.props.history.goBack()}` will execute the goBack function on render.